# Is it possible to format a cell for href's alone

Tags: excel

We would like to format an excel cell just to contain href values. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the cell to be a hyperlink but without visible text, like a blank button to click upon (it's not clear from your question what you want), you can set the text color to be the same as the background color.

Comment: Just want the cell to accept href's alone (e.g. users should not store a date or number or something else). Using the format cell feature

Comment: @user339108 I do not believe that what you want is possible. Here is a post from Microsoft on [the types of data validation that are supported](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/211485). You would need a regex or some such to enforce only 'hrefs'.